# AngularJS ngGrid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Cannot read property 'aggLabelFilter' of undefined

I get the following error when enabling the Group option of ngGrid.  Chrome DevTools shows the error [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/v2wI9t?p=preview)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'aggLabelFilter' of undefined
at self.parseGroupData (angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js:2456)
at self.getGrouping (angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js:2553)
at self.filteredRowsChanged (angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js:2370)
at self.evalFilter (angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js:2675)
at dataWatcher (angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js:3286)
at Object.fn (angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js:3297)
at Object.e.$digest (angular.min.js:84)
at Object.e.$apply (angular.min.js:86)
at angular.min.js:15
at Object.d [as invoke] (angular.min.js:26)angular.min.js:60 (anonymous function)
```

If I remove the `groups: 'GameDate',` from the JS, then this works without an error.

I updated the Group setting to be an array as suggested, but the error persists.  I then tried to disable the groups setting and the grousCollapsedByDefault, and enabled the ShowGroupPanel.  While the error now goes away, as soon as I drag the GameDate column to the grid shows the groupings. Once I expand the group, then the error occurs again.

When expanding the group columns, I get one instance of the following error for each collapsed row of data.

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/ueoe?p0=row.entity.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ng-grid documentation:

groups  []  Initial fields to group data by. Array of field names, not displayName.

so if you change

`groups: 'GameDate'`

to

`groups: ['GameDate']`

should work without problems

Comment: I tried it with the array setting `groups: ['GameDate']` and it still gives me the same error. I updated the plunker as well.

Comment: @StevenScott [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RKHZitZOwRe2tzGAwem8) I see other errors but they are not related to mentioned before.

Comment: True. As my update says I now get new errors on pretty much the same code. Not sure how to clear the new ones up with groups in use.

Comment: @StevenScott what errors are you getting? take a look at this [screen](http://pbrd.co/1Gm7Jhu), the only error I see is plnk stuff

Comment: I am getting the last code error in the question now, which is        Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/ueoe?p0=row.entity.   I thought this might be from the GULP combine etc..., but I have copied the Plunker files to a local drive to just try it in Chrome.

Comment: It must be Gulp showing the other errors, as stripping this down and putting it into a single folder does work without error. Thanks.